# Override lock screen with activity for alarm application

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarm, receiver

I am working on a different type of alarm application and cannot seem to figure out how to have it so that when the alarm goes off and is received, if the screen is off, it will turn on and open right up to the applications activity to turn off the alarm.

Basically the same way that the regular google clock does it.

I added these to my Manifest file as well as the proper receiver and service tags.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

I have the **Alarm Receiver** class that handles the receive and calls a **Wake Lock** class;
Here is the receiver below.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  WakeLocker.acquire(context);
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
  context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

And here is the beginning of the RingtonPlayingService class that is called after it is received. I handle the playing of the sound later in this class but didn't feel it was needed to show.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intentMain = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentMain, 0);
```

And then in the **MainActivity** I added these flags which seem to work for a lot of people.

```
getWindow().addFlags(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

I put them before the setContentView call.

I guess I am unsure of the process and order that everything needs to be in, in order for this to work.

What I thought was that the pending intent was created in the mainActivity and once that alarm was fired, the receiver picked it up and fired the RingtonePlayingService, which handled the playing of the actual alarm sound. Then that activity fired to open another activity with all the flags on it that would turn the screen on and override the lock screen.